# Making a formula that checks for a sheet with the same name as the cell next to it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula which sums up several columns in another sheet. The sheet that the formula is referencing to always has the same name as the cell next to it.

[image]

Instead of having to rewrite the formula for every cell in the column, is there a way I can just simply check for a sheet with the same name as the cell next to it? The cell ranges will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use INDIRECT formula. This allows you to write references as strings.

Instead of 'Round 3'!C5:C you can write: INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!C5:C") (assuming that word Round 3 is in C3).

Whole function looks like this (assuming that active cell is D2)

```
 =SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!C5:C"),INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!G5:G"),INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!K5:K"),INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!O5:O"),INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!S5:S"))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! I tried messing about with indirect but I didn't know how to do multiple ranges and that you had to use indirect several times.

How can I change this formula to show as blank if it equals 0? I have a big collumn and it doesn't look very nice with all the 0's.

Comment: I know I can write it like this

=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!C5:C"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!G5:G"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!K5:K"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!O5:O"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!S5:S")) = 0 , "" , SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!C5:C"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!G5:G"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!K5:K"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!O5:O"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!S5:S")))

But I of course want to avoid that lol.

Comment: When you like my answer, then please vote up. If you want to eliminate zeros from your spreadsheet you should use custom format for these cells: Use Format --> More formats ---> Custom format, and then type 0;-0;; as a format.